# Drawing Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $C ⊆ \mathbb R^2$ be the unit square whose vertices are $(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)$, and $(1, 1)$.

Let S ◦ T: $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and  T ◦ S: $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix}$

Draw, on separate axes, the image of C under the transformations (i) S ◦ T and (ii) T ◦ S, clearly labelling each image.

My intuition is to get all the x,y coordinates of post transformation like this:

(i) $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

and plot all of these values

(ii) $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 2\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$

and these values on a separate axis

Comment: This is correct. You could also use the fact that the images of the canonical basic vectors are the columns of your matrix. Thus, via $S\circ T$, $(1,0)$ goes to $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$. Then you complete the parallelogram, which is the image of the original square.